# Setting CAGradientlayer as background of CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, calayer, cashapelayer

I have a CAShapeLayer whose color i want to be a gradient. I am trying to set CAGradientlayer as a sublayer of CAShapeLayer but the gradient is not appearing.

Here's my code

```
    CAShapeLayer* shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.frame = _borderLayer.bounds;
    shapeLayer.bounds = _borderLayer.bounds;
    shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
    shapeLayer.fillColor = nil;
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10.0f;
    shapeLayer.hidden = YES;

    CAGradientLayer* gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    //gradientLayer.colors = @[[UIColor blueColor],[UIColor greenColor]];
    NSMutableArray* colors = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [colors addObject:(id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];
    [colors addObject:(id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor];
    gradientLayer.colors = colors;
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0);
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);

    [shapeLayer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
```

Comment: Your gradient layer doesn't appear to have a frame.

Comment: yes was able to figure it out.